# Android findViewById in service

Tags: android

I am doing something like when a service get started, a custom toast notification shows up.

The custom toast view is defined in a xml file, the problem is that `findViewById` is not available in Service class.

Since it's a bad idea to start an activity in a service. So, how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

check this post

http://www.cloud208.com/blogica/Android+Custom+Toast+from+a+Service

According to that post, you can use an inflater with `null` as the second argument:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.toast_layout, null);
```

Comment: The link is destroyed !