# Not able to use findViewbyId in Service

Tags: android, android-service, findviewbyid

I am doing an application where I should use the Service to open a PopUpwindow at certain Intervals of time. I tried it by keeping the popup window code in other activity as method and calling it in the service. But it ended up in vain. So I have copied all popupWindow code to the service here I cannot use findViewById.

My service code is as follows

```
public class TimeService extends Service {
View layout;
LayoutInflater inflater;
public PopupWindow pw;
private RadioGroup options_group;
private RadioButton option_button;
Button submit_popup,close_popup;

// constant
public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 10 * 10000; // 100 seconds

// run on another Thread to avoid crash
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
// timer handling
private Timer mTimer = null;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // cancel if already existed


    if (mTimer != null) {
        mTimer.cancel();

    } else {
        // recreate new
        mTimer = new Timer();
    }
    // schedule task
    mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
}

class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // run on another thread
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // display toast
                try {

                    inflater = (LayoutInflater) TimeService.this.
                            getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_1));

                    pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300, 370, true);
                    pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

                    submit_popup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.popup_submit);
                    close_popup = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.popup_cancel);
                    options_group=(RadioGroup) layout.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

                    submit_popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            pw.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    submit_popup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int selectedId=options_group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            option_button=(RadioButton) layout.findViewById(selectedId);

                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        });
    }


}
}
```

I am getting error in the line

```
 layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_1));
```

and the error is cannot resolve method findViewbyId(int).

Please help me with the code. What I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried using the code

```
layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_popup, null);
```

I am getting the error or stacktrace as follows

```
 07-22 01:17:39.789 940-957/system_process W/WindowManager: Attempted to add window with token that is not a window: null.  Aborting.
07-22 01:17:39.790 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
07-22 01:17:39.790 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:562)
07-22 01:17:39.790 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
07-22 01:17:39.790 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
07-22 01:17:39.790 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1104)
07-22 01:17:39.790 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:933)
07-22 01:17:39.790 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:897)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at highski.developers.cflash.service.TimeService$TimeDisplayTimerTask$1$override.run(TimeService.java:85)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at highski.developers.cflash.service.TimeService$TimeDisplayTimerTask$1$override.access$dispatch(TimeService.java)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at highski.developers.cflash.service.TimeService$TimeDisplayTimerTask$1.run(TimeService.java:0)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-22 01:17:39.791 27060-27060/highski.developers.cflash W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Read this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992748/android-findviewbyid-in-service

Comment: @mayurvpatel110 I have read that and tried that but it dint reach my requirements and I have done that to. U can see the system error I am getting when I make the parameter null.

Comment: @KarrthikReddy have you solved the problem

Comment: No I havent. @SaravInfern

Answer (score 3):

you cannot directly make changes in ui inside a service instead use broadcast receiver and intent filter to notify your activity/fragment and update from there

How to service works
[image: see how service works]

Some use reference onservices

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

https://androidexperinz.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/communication-between-service-and-activity-part-1/

Comment: Thank you @SaravInfern. I am having a look at it. Will be back when I see that Completely.

Comment: you can also refer here if you are trying to show an alert dialog http://stackoverflow.com/a/21929839/6414107

Answer (score 1):

Pass null values in 2nd parameter

```
  layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup_1));
```

to

```
 layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_popup, null);
```

**Update:**

```
 private Handler mHandler;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    //... do like above and remove perivous updated 
}
```

Comment: I made an edit to the question please have a look at it.

Comment: That did not help me got another system error  java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Handler

```
private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if (msg.what == 0) {
            // add your code here.
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

add call the handler in ua Run() method.

```
handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

All the best.

Comment: your answer doesn't match with the question requirements at all

Answer (score 0):

**See the Answer Here**

[Show dialog alert from a non-activity class in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059545/show-dialog-alert-from-a-non-activity-class-in-android)

The problem is '`You can show AlertDialogs ,dialog or Popupwindow from your Service Activity only`'.

**Although this is not a good idea to show dialog from receiver or Service** (better is to use Notification), But if you want to do so you can create an [Activity as dialog and show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766739/show-an-alert-dialog-in-broadcast-receiver-after-a-system-reboot)

Answer (score 0):

AlertDialog should be managed by Activity which has a window, since Service is a non-UI component, so you cannot show a dialog in the service, otherwise app will crash:

> Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
>
> at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:325)

You have two ways to show dialog in service:

1, Start a dialog theme activity, and show a dialog in this activity's `onCreate` method.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
```

OR

2, Set the dialog as system alert:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    builder.setTitle("title")
           .setMessage("message");
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    // set the dialog as system alert
    dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    dialog.show();
```