# Interrupt waiting process android

Tags: java, android

I have a foreground Service which executes once a day, but if I click on a button the Service should terminate. But my Problem is I don't know how to stop the waiting process, because I can't stop the Service until the waiting process is running.

Code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

  timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
        //some Code
        //Button should be around here but I'm not sure if that works 
     }
}, TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1),TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1));
```

Can someone tell me how to stop the above waiting process by clicking a button?

Answer (score 2):

Try somethnig like this :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timer.cancel();
                timer.purge();
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you know how i get the button in the Service class because `Button button = findViewbyID()` does not work

Comment: Can you provide more code please i can't help if i can't see the code @user12346352

Comment: sure call you tell me what else you Need so i don't put Code in it you don't even need

Comment: The service class, the part where you need to get the `button`

Comment: Or you can check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992748/android-findviewbyid-in-service @user12346352

Comment: Thank you but it doesn't work Maybe because i click the button until the Service waits and so it's not possible to stop the Sleep and the Service. Maybe you should also know thats all running in a Thread and as Foreground hopefully that makes no difference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174930/discussion-between-user12346352-and-b-m).